# Pip installation of PyInstaller failing on Windows

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to turn a Python file into an executable file with pyinstaller but I can't install pyinstall with `pip install pyinstaller` from cmd.
I get this error when I am trying to install pyinstaller:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\Olgun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-bdh65vkf\pyinstaller-5.7.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl'.

I don't know if there is something wrong with my Python directory.

I tried to change the Windows file directory length limit but it was already at max limit. I tried using py2exe but it doesn't support the current Python version.

Comment: Temporary Disable the Windows Defender and Install again. this should fix the error.